# Functional code in overleaf does not work in local texmaker

Tags: overleaf, texmaker, apa7

I created a template for articles in apa7-Format using the apa7 package. The code works fine in overleaf. When I copy and paste it in texmaker, the code produces a lot of problems. In contrast to overleaf, I get the error message that \begin{document} would be missing, although I put it in the code after the preample. Also, texmaker does not seem to recognize the \shorttitle preamble e.g. properly. I did search several online sources and I think I set up my texmaker according to the suggestions there. Therefore, I'm out of troubleshooting ideas. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{ef_short_report.bib}

\title{Sample APA-Style Document Using the \textsf{apa7} Package}
\shorttitle{Sample Document}

\author{JK}
\affiliation{A University Somewhere}

\leftheader{K}

\abstract{\lipsum[1]}

\keywords{APA style, demonstration}

\authornote{
   \addORCIDlink{JK}{0000-0000-0000-0000}

  Correspondence concerning this article should be addressed to J K, Department of XYZ, Medical Center, City, Country
  00000.  E-mail: j.k@blabla.de}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\Textcite{Beers.2002d} said this,
too \parencite{Augusti.2013,Evans.2013}.  Further evidence comes from
other sources \parencite{Barrera.2013}.
\lipsum[3]

\printbibliography

\appendix

\end{document}
```

And this is the error message I am getting:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.10.12) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.11.10) 10 NOV 2023 15:42
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**./apa7_temp.tex
(apa7_temp.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-11-01>
(apa7.cls
Document Style `res' <26 Sep 89>.
LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class `apa7',
but the document class provides `res'.
Document Class: res 2000/05/19 v1.4b Resume class
(C:\Users\Jan\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\Jan\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count186
\c@section=\count187
\c@subsection=\count188
\c@subsubsection=\count189
\c@paragraph=\count190
\c@subparagraph=\count191
\c@figure=\count192
\c@table=\count193
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
No auxiliary output files.
\tabular@text=\toks17
\tabular@head=\toks18
\tabular@tail=\toks19
\@ta=\toks20
\undefined@token=\toks21
\sectionwidth=\dimen141
\sectionskip=\skip50
\resumewidth=\dimen142
\@columnwidth=\dimen143
\c@numberofcolumns=\count194
) (C:\Users\Jan\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/csquotes\csquotes.sty
Package: csquotes 2022-09-14 v5.2n context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
(C:\Users\Jan\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count195
)
(C:\Users\Jan\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks22
)
\csq@reset=\count196
\csq@gtype=\count197
\csq@glevel=\count198
\csq@qlevel=\count199
\csq@maxlvl=\count266
\csq@tshold=\count267
\csq@ltx@everypar=\toks23
(C:\Users\Jan\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/csquotes\csquotes.def
File: csquotes.def 2022-09-14 v5.2n csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
)
Package csquotes Info: Trying to load configuration file 'csquotes.cfg'...
Package csquotes Info: ... configuration file loaded successfully.
(C:\Users\Jan\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/csquotes\csquotes.cfg
File: csquotes.cfg
))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \shorttitle
{jk}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.9 \shorttitle{j
k}
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \affiliation
{UKL}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.13 \leftheader
{Keil}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.13 \leftheader{K
eil}
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.15 \abstract
{here comes the abstract}
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.17 \keywords
{maltreatment, cooperation}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.19 \authornote
{
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.20 \addORCIDlink
{Jan Keil}{0000-0002-5001-0659}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
Package csquotes Info: Checking for multilingual support...
Package csquotes Info: ... none found.
(C:\Users\Jan\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdfte
x.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-10-23 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count268
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
)
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
[jou].
No file apa7_temp.aux.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 25.
[1
{C:/Users/Jan/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <12> on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <8> on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <6> on input line 26.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Ackerman.2008' on page 2 undefined on input line 30.
[2]
***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-11-01>
***********
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
1515 strings out of 474591
24869 string characters out of 5746721
1925533 words of memory out of 5000000
23749 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
562019 words of font info for 49 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
49i,6n,52p,275b,202s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<C:/Users/Jan/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cm
bx10.pfb><C:/Users/Jan/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfont
s/cm/cmbx9.pfb><C:/Users/Jan/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/a
msfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Users/Jan/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/pu
blic/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/Users/Jan/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/ty
pe1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb><C:/Users/Jan/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr9.pfb>
Output written on C:\Users\Jan\Desktop\apa7\build\apa7_temp.pdf (2 pages, 77649
bytes).
PDF statistics:
39 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Comment: overleaf/texmaker do not matter here what matters is the version of the various packages. Your example runs without error in texlive 2023 apart from the missing `Figure1.pdf`  error (you could use `example-image` instead, which would work.  Show the full error message that you get (or better, full log file) from the error case

Comment: the `\begin{document}` missing error does not mean that it is not in the file, it means latex saw something that is not allowed before `\begin{document}` which means one of your packages is trying to typeset text rather than just make definitions. the full message would show the context. You could dimplify your example and remove all the text between `\begin{document}` and `\end[document}` as that presumably gives the same error.

Comment: I've tested with TeX Live 2020, 2021, 2022, and 2023: No error (after replacing `Figure1.pdf` by `example-image` as recommended by David). Maybe there was an error in an aux-file. So clearing the cache could help. If not, see David's comments above.

Comment: This is the error message I get: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \shorttitle
               {jk}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Comment: so the begin document error is spurious. as `\shortitle` is not known, the following `{jk}` is taken as text and it tries to start a paragraph at that point in the preamble so generates the error. If you showed the log as requested you would see tex highlights that spot. You would also see that (presumably) you have a non standard version of  apa7 installed, but with no information  shown so far we can't really help

Comment: I see. I'm not really sure how I can best share the information needed. Is there a good way to upload the logfile?

Comment: you presumably don't get  ` ! Undefined control sequence. l.9 \shorttitle {jk}` from the code posted which has  `\shorttitle{Sample Document}`  don't paraphrase error messages it makes it impossible to debug, show the full log from the code posted.

Comment: add it as a code block to your question. as your run stops on line 9 the log is presumably not very long

Comment: you could make the log a lot shorter by removing lipsum. babel and biblatex packages, which I assume are not needed to show the error

Comment: Sure, I did that. Could it have something to do with conflicting document classes (res vs. apa7)?

Comment: `apa7.cls
Document Style \`res' <26 Sep 89>.`  ??????????  You have localy copied  a truely historic `res.cls` (dated 4 years before LaTeX2e was written!!!!)  to `apa7.cls` so preventing the `apa7.cls` that is in miktex being used.  There is no chance anything works with that file, where did you find it??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149630/discussion-between-jan-and-david-carlisle).